# Computer not connecting to any WiFi

Tags: windows, windows-10, wifi-configuration

I have a computer running Windows 10, and is incompatible with Windows 11, if that’s important.

Basically, at random times, with no rhyme or reason, the WiFi drops, and no networks show up under available networks. That might be weird enough, but when I go to network/internet settings, and click troubleshoot, it goes through the whole process, and I then whether says “problem with wireless access point” or “computer not set to automatically connect to *name of internet address withheld for my safety*”

It sometimes says both. I have tried doing a network reset and it broke again, I’ve reset me computer multiple times, fixed for a bit, then half an hour later, bam, broken. I’ve tried scanning for a virus, nothing. I have no idea what’s going on and it’s driving me mad.

No other devices have this issue. This is the computer that I am using : https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-prodesk-600-g1-desktop-mini-pc/6595197/model/6595201?sku=K1K25UT

Comment: Can you tell us more about your setup? Who's the manufacturer of the wireless chipset and it's model? What about the router make / model?  Using 2.4ghz or 5ghz?  Does this issue only happen on this computer, but other devices never drop (e.g. your mobile phone stays connected with no drops)?

Comment: How do I update the routers, and I also can’t update the firmware on my router. None of my other devices have this problem either.

Comment: @spaceman-spiff this is the exact pc that isn’t working, and no other devices have this issue. https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-prodesk-600-g1-desktop-mini-pc/6595197/model/6595201?sku=K1K25UT

Comment: I was told I can’t, it’s an AT&T router. How would I do it if I could?

Comment: Looks like you probably have an Intel wireless chipset.  While the normal advice is to rely on the OEM supplier to get your driver updates, you could try getting Intel to update the wireless drivers using their utility - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html

Comment: I’ll try that, once my computer boots. I had to restart it